# TypeError: string indices must be integers in EntityRuler

Tags: python, spacy

There are quite a few questions and answers on SO regarding `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. However, they are not applicable to my case, thus this question

I have the following code using `EntityRuler` of spaCy

```
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

patterns = {"label": "BUSI", "pattern": [{'LOWER': 'store'}]}

# Initialise a ruler with a new pattern and add it to the processing pipeline
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

text = 'Store 1 is in LA but store 2 in NY.'

# Display the text with highlighted keywords on screen
svg = spacy.displacy.render(nlp(text), style='ent', jupyter=True)
```

However, I got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-68d5c254c098> in <module>()
      9 # Initialise a ruler with new patterns and add it to the processing pipeline
     10 ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
---> 11 ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
     12 nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
     13 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\entityruler.py in add_patterns(self, patterns)
    178         """
    179         for entry in patterns:
--> 180             label = entry["label"]
    181             if "id" in entry:
    182                 label = self._create_label(label, entry["id"])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I simply can't tell what `string indices` refers to. Is it `entry["label"]`? Could you please show me how can I fix it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your patterns should be like this:

```
patterns = [{"label": "BUSI", "pattern": [{'LOWER': 'store'}]}]
```